# Facebook Ads API conversion pixel custom variables reporting

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am trying access the custom parameters for the  I've set within my Facebook pixel for the Purchase event. The developer documentation doesn't address my question so I'm looking for help. Has anyone been successful at accessing these custom(dynamic) variables through the Marketing API so that we can report on purchase amount, time/date, product purchased, purchase(order) id?

Thanks,
Matthew

```js
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

fbq('init', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
fbq('track', 'PageView');
  fbq('track', 'Purchase', {
    content_name: {{prodName}},
    content_category: {{prodCat}},
    content_ids: {{prodID}},
    content_type: 'product',
    order_id: {{orderID}},
    value: {{orderRev}},
    currency: 'USD'
});    

</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Comment: did you ever figure this out?